# C# and GDAL implementation - Dataset not returning a value

Tags: c#, .net-core, gis, rgdal

I am trying to automate a simple geotiff to KMZ process using GDAL and C#

The code I have written is a little buggy and I am having a lot of trouble working out how to use the API. I am hoping this is a simple fix for more advanced developers.

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OSGeo.GDAL;

namespace TestingTIFFtoKMZ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string outputName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\BR01899_Mackenzie_09_EXPORT";
            string vrtfile = outputName + @"\tempMosaic.vrt";
            string filenameKMZ = outputName + @"\" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + ".kmz";
            string[] tiffFiles = Directory.GetFiles(outputName, "*.tif");

            var vrtOptions = new GDALBuildVRTOptions(new[] { "-overwrite" });

            GDALTranslateOptions transOptions = new GDALTranslateOptions(new[] { "-of", "KMLSUPEROVERLAY", "-co", "format=png" });

            Dataset vrtDataset = Gdal.wrapper_GDALBuildVRT_names(vrtfile, tiffFiles, vrtOptions, null, null);
            // vrtDataset.Dispose();

            Gdal.wrapper_GDALTranslate(filenameKMZ, vrtDataset, transOptions, null, null);


        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a null return value on the vrtDataset variable and (i think) as a result, I am getting a null reference error when I call the Gdal.wrapperGDALTranslate method.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It needed,

Gdal.AllRegister();

and an absolute path to the VRT file being created.